# Retrive date object from datetime.date in specific format

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

How can I retrieve a `date` object (NOT `datetime` object) from the `datetime` class in `%m/%d/%y` format?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Can you add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about what you want to do?or the code that you have tried so far because SO is not a code writing service!

Answer (score 2):

You'd just format the `datetime` with that format, using the [`datetime.datetime.strftime()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime):

```
date_string = dt.strftime('%m/%d/%y')
```

You don't *have* to use the time components at all when formatting a string.

If you wanted a date *object* (a `datetime.date()` instance), call the [`datetime.datetime.date()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date):

```
date_object = dt.date()
```

Note that `datetime.date()` instances support [string formatting too](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime).

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.now()
>>> dt.strftime('%m/%d/%y')
'07/09/15'
>>> dt.date()
datetime.date(2015, 7, 9)
>>> dt.date().strftime('%m/%d/%y')
'07/09/15'
```

Comment: yesterday = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(1)
        yesterday = yesterday.strftime('%m/%d/%y')
        yesterday = yesterday.date()

Comment: @RahulAhuja: why are you trying to call `.date()` on a formatted string? Pick one or the other, either you get a formatted string, **or** you get a date object.

Comment: Your code returns a string at last, i want a date object

Comment: @RahulAhuja because your question appeared to ask for a formatted string. I gave you various *options*. If you want a date object don't use `strftime`, simple as that.

Comment: @RahulAhuja: note for example where I say *If you wanted a date object (a datetime.date() instance), call the datetime.datetime.date() method*?